# Show that $x^3 +x-1$ has a zero between $x=0$ and $x=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Show that $x^3 +x-1$ has a zero between $x=0$ and $x=1$, does anyone know how to go about starting this problem? I am basically clueless. I thought maybe at first polynomial division since its $x^3$, but I don't think it is.

Comment: Try using the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: ahh ok thanks, i will try that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(x) = x^3+x-1$ is a continuous function.

$f(0) = -1
\\
f(1) = 1
$

Because it is a continuous function, all possible values between $-1$ and $1$ exist, including $0$.

Answer (score 1):

There is not even the intermediate value theorem required. [Bolzanos Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BolzanosTheorem.html) is sufficient already - since it states that for every function $f$ which is continuous in the closed interval $[a,b]$ and for which is true $f(a) < 0 $ and $f(b) > 0$ there must exist a zero-point of $f$ in that interval.

Comment: IVT is just a more general case of Bolzano's Theorem, just as MVT is just a more general case of Rolle's Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

> **The intermediate value theorem** states that if a continuous function $f$ with an interval $[a, b]$ as its domain takes values $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ at each end of the interval, then it also takes any value between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ at some point within the interval.

Let $f(x)=x^3+x-1$, you have that $f$ is continuous everywhere since it is a polynomial. Now calculate $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ and conclude.